# Mongoose has no connect method when loading via Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, browserify

I am able to load Mongoose in an interactive `node` session and view its `connect` method like so...

```
> var mongoose = require("mongoose/");    
> mongoose.connect
[Function]
```

...But when loading Mongoose via Browserify, the method is missing. The following code...

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose/");
console.log(mongoose);
```

...logs the following in Chrome:

```
Object {Error: function, Schema: function, Types: Object, VirtualType: function, SchemaType: function…}
Document: function Document(obj, schema, fields, skipId, skipInit) {
Error: function MongooseError(msg) {
Schema: function Schema(obj, options) {
SchemaType: function SchemaType(path, options, instance) {
Types: Object
VirtualType: function VirtualType(options, name) {
utils: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I imagine I'm doing something relatively stupid, but for the life of me I cannot determine what. [This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386101/mongoose-has-no-method-connect), but the proposed solution does not fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose in the browser doesn't expose most of the methods that are available when using it in node.js. You can use it to create schemas and validate objects against the schema, but that's about it.

[Mongoose in the Browser](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html)

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I even went to that page and didn't read very carefully. I'm trying to build an isomorphic app but haven't gotten to the point of wiring up anything on the node.js side. I see now that I should probably get on that for mongoose connectivity...

Comment: We try to use Browserify to pack our node.js app, but it seems that it packs mongoose "for browser". Do you know why browserify enables sort of "browser environment"?